# DipTrace bottom layer pad shape

Tags: pcb-design, cad, diptrace

I'm having a problem in DipTrace. I'm trying to change the shape of the pads on the bottom layer. I have successfully created and had etched a similar PCB in DipTrace yesterday, and have followed the same rules today, but it just doesn't want to change.

On my previous PCB, changing pad properties changes both top and bottom layers shape etc, but this project, it seems that the shaped is locked on the bottom layer. No matter what pad property I change, the change is only reflected on the top layer.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this PCB is getting printed onto acetate then going in an etch tank I have figured out a workaround. I previewed the PCB, and selected Layers > Show > All layers, and Layers > Current > Top. I then deselected all the objects in the Objects menu that weren't going to print. This left me with exactly what I wanted, albeit in a rather botched manner. This method is pretty useless if you are doing anything other than single layer DIY etching without silk screens etc. Hopefully this answer may be of some use to someone.